# Swift playgrounds failing for no reason

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I created a little script in swift playgrounds(IPad version not Xcode):

```
var alfs = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m","."]// to avoid complications First loop does not use spaces as an option
var alf = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m",""]
public var successes: [String] = [] 

//checks if the string has already been listed
func hasRepeated(str: String)->Bool {
    var flag = false
    for i in successes {
        if i == str {
            flag = true
        }
    }
    if str.contains("/./") || str.contains("/../") {
        flag = true
    }
    
    return flag
}
var url:URL! = nil
var path:String = ""
// this is the function where the errors occurr
func test(files:String) {
    path = files
    //searches for a file name that is four characters or less
    for m in alfs {
        path.append(m)
    for u in alf {
        path.append(u)
        for d in alf {
            path.append(d)
            //the error usually occurrs in this for loop
            for c in alf {
                path.append(c)
                path.append("/")
                do {
                    url = try URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                    if  ( try url.checkResourceIsReachable()) {
                        if !hasRepeated(str: path) {
                            show(path)
                            successes.append(path)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    
                }
                path.remove(at: path.lastIndex(of: Character("/"))!)
                if c != "" {
                    if let index = path.lastIndex(of: Character(c)) {path.remove(at: index)}
                }
            }
            if d != "" {
                if let index = path.lastIndex(of: Character(d)) {path.remove(at: index)}
            }
        }
        if u != "" {
            if let index = path.lastIndex(of: Character(u)) {path.remove(at: index)}
        }
    }
        if m != "" {
            if let index = path.lastIndex(of: Character(m)) {path.remove(at: index)}
        }
    }
}
test(files: "/")
show("____________________")
while successes.count != 0  {
    var suggse: [String] = []
    for i in successes {
        suggse.append(i)
    }
    successes.removeAll()
    for i in suggse {
            test(files: i)
    }
    show("____________________")
}
show("goodbye")
```

If you run this in an answers playground it will run through some names (/usr/, /.mb/, /etc/) but then on the second round it will fail with the playgrounds default error, “There was a problem encountered while running this playground. Check your code for mistakes.” This error occurs at a random line(usually in the deepest for loop) and sometimes it happens in the try catch statement.

The web was not very helpful as I couldn’t find what I was looking for.

Why does this happen? Please help.

Comment: don't use `try!` use `do { try ... } catch { print(error) }` and see what error you get

Comment: and don't force unwrap the result of `lastIndex` method. use `if let index = ...` and then `remove(at: index)`

Comment: You could also run this as a Swift script to get more specific diagnostics. Put it in a file `main.swift`, open Terminal, and run `swift main.swift` in that directory. It should give you a more specific error

Comment: Sam I will try that when I have the desktop computer(at the end of the week)

Comment: Leo Dabus I tried your second comment and it failed like usual, however for your first comment I could not find the `try!` That is not enclosed in a do catch statement.

Comment: In your first version, there was `url = try! URL(fileURLWithPath: path)`, but it disappeared.

Comment: Ok, So I ran it with ubuntu and it ran perfectly however I need my code to be run on the ipad. I guess swift playgrounds is just unstable.